# Adblock extension blocks Magento product images

Tags: template, theme, grid, grid-serlization, design

I have realized that the Adblock extension blocks all my product item images from [this Magento site](http://cavalet.bg).

I want to make my site visible also for users with the Adblock extension installed. The problem is that AdBlock filters all **180x150** images in the `cavalet.bg/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x150` folder.

How can I change the path where all my product images are saved? What can I do with all my images already saved in 180x150 folder?

Many thanks!

Comment: please provides us more details

Comment: Avoid naming your products "Viagra".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What kind of details do you need? I think it's all about tags names and classes? All products are art paintings and not "Viagra".

Comment: let you give the ruleset the adblock plus user uses and see which of this rules apply to this url.

Comment: Can't you just make the images 190x160 and use CSS with some `overflow:hidden` div to clip them? Saves you a lot of trouble and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adblock Plus for Firefox. CTRL + SHIFT + F pulls up Filter preferences window.

Use Filter Actions button to change the View to show at least Enabled, Filter Rule, Hits and Last Hit.

Sort by Last Hit to float your current page issues to the top

[image]

From the background, you can see the images are missing. Filter at top with last hit is /180x150/* which must be a common size for ad images otherwise there probably wouldn't be this rule. Uncheck the Enabled checkbox for the rule and reload page.

[image]

Note that the images are back. Change template to 182x152 for image size and call it a day?

Comment: Thanks! What can I do with all my images already saved in 180x150 folder?

Comment: If you change the template to be a slightly different size, Magento will automatically create and populate a new folder structure for the new images. You can then after making sure this taboo size isn't used in your templates, delete the 180x150 folder. Personally, the Adblock rule is kind of ridiculous as it's an easily sidestepped rule that only serves to annoy legitimate web developers and leads to ruleset warfare as whoever they're trying to block catches on and resize their images to pass as well.

Comment: Or since it's an e-commerce website and there's a ridiculous number of standard px by px rules in Adblock Plus, you could have a text underlay behind a prominent image that you purposefully fix up so it is matched and blocked. And have the text say **This site displays better with Adblock disabled on this domain. We're only trying to sell you our product, not send you to some other website so it's to our mutual advantage that you see everything on the site.**

Comment: Do you think I could resolve my problem just by chanching the folder's name somehow and preserve the original image size?

Comment: Not really, you're asking to go the hard way around. Resized images in a folder in Magento's eyes are not really worth that much, it recreates them far too easily. Changing the folder's name runs counter to how Magento works as it is a CMS that automatically takes care of image resizing, image storage and path creation. You will have to write a module that changes the URL string for save operations, image retrieval and display, etc. It's easier to change the template image pixel dimensions and leave the automatic file system stuff to Magento.

Comment: So the solution was really easy - I just changed the resize values and preserved the old width and height:  `<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(181, 151); ?>" width="180" height="150" />`

Comment: After some reflections I changed the original height size with one pixel because the browser's resizing algorithms are optimized for speed, not quality. In this way I preserved the best (original) image quality.

Comment: Working well now with Adblock Plus turned on and looking really nice!

Answer (score 1):

You are the best [copola](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3441/capola)!
this solved the issue: `<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(181, 151); ?>" width="180" height="150" />`

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Is this supposed to be a "Thank you" comment or an actual solution to the problem, which has not been mentioned before? If the latter, please remove "you are the best, copola". That's nice, but confusing. StackExchange works differently than a forum ;)